# MAMP PRO doesn't allow me to change PHP version over hosts

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

I don't know why but for some reason my MAMP PRO doesn't allow me to change PHP version over host. I'm using MAMP PRO 4. If you take a look you will notice the option for that is disabled,

I left here a screenshot,

[MAMP PRO configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuqwS.png)

Any idea?,

Regards!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I just resolved. The error was running PHP as module mode, if you want to have multiples version for each vhost you must run as CGI

Comment: To run as CGI Mode, click on PHP on the side, then switch the mode to "Individual PHP version for every host (CGI mode)" and save.

Answer (score 7):

To run a different PHP version on each host, go Languages > PHP > Individual PHP version for every host (CGI mode).

Return to Settings > Hosts and under the host a dropdown should be available to choose your PHP version.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helped me.  For those using Windows MAMP PRO 5.  You need to go to the main dropdown menu 'View' -> 'PHP' these options shown above are found there.

Answer (score 3):

**Possibility 1:** your server is running (you cannot change php version when the serving is running)

**Possibility 2:** you only have 1 version of php installed on your computer

Comment: Sorry but is not the case. I'm not new using this program It's only happens after I updated from MAMP PRO 3. This is really weird. Thanks! Any other advise?